# WPF Modify Path Data at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, path, geometry

Hi I have a path from GetFlattenedPathGeometry where i can iterate through the figures and segments to get the points to add to a PointCollection.

I then multiply each point.x/y by a scale factor to get a full scaled version of the original path data. (not using scaletransform as it doesn't suit my requirements).

If i use something like:

```
public static PathGeometry GetPathGeometry(PointCollection polygonCorners)
{
    List<PathSegment> pathSegments = new List<PathSegment> { new     PolyLineSegment(polygonCorners, true) };
    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(new PathFigure(polygonCorners[0], pathSegments, true));
    return pathGeometry;
}
```

It returns a new path geometry but doesn't handle ellipses with excluded path geometry in that the path is just one continuous line.

Is there a way to convert the PointCollection to Path.Data (eg: with the "M" "L" and such) for me to re-use Geometry.Parse(the new string)?

Here is the code i'm using to get the flattenedgeometry pointcollection:

```
PathGeometry g = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
foreach (var f in g.Figures)
{
    foreach (var s in f.Segments)
    {
        if (s is PolyLineSegment)
        {
            foreach (var pt in ((PolyLineSegment) s).Points)
            {
                strGeom += pt.ToString();
                Point ptn = new Point(pt.X * ScaleX, pt.Y * ScaleY);
                pcol.Add(ptn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

< Edit Images >

Here is the original path with rectangles and ellipses subtracted from the geometry.

[image]

And here is what is looks like re-creating from the code.

[image]

If i use the original GetFlattenedPathGeometry, it looks like the original but i need to scale the points to a new resolution.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call `ToString` on the PathGeometry to get the whole path data string at once:

```
var sourceGeometry = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
var geometryString = sourceGeometry.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var targetGeometry = Geometry.Parse(geometryString);
```

---

And why can't you just apply a ScaleTransform to the whole geometry before calling GetFlattenedPathGeometry? The following works perfectly for me (with two EllipseGeometries in an excluding CombinedGeometry):

```
var pathGeometry = path.Data.Clone();
pathGeometry.Transform = new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5);
var scaledGeometry = pathGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
```

---

EDIT: From what you write in your question and  comments, I'm guessing that all you actually want to do is to add or combine geometries with different scaling factors. If that is true, your flattened geometry approach is by far to complicated, as you could easily do that with the following two methods:

```
private PathGeometry AddGeometries(
    Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2, double scale)
{
    geometry2 = geometry2.Clone();
    geometry2.Transform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
    var pathGeometry = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(geometry1);
    pathGeometry.AddGeometry(geometry2);
    return pathGeometry;
}

private PathGeometry CombineGeometries(
    Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2, GeometryCombineMode mode, double scale)
{
    geometry2 = geometry2.Clone();
    geometry2.Transform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
    return Geometry.Combine(geometry1, geometry2, mode, null);
}
```

Given a Path with some geometry in its Data property, you may now add (or combine) an arbitray other geometry with a scaling factor with a call like this:

```
Geometry newGeometry1 = ...
double scale1 = ...
path.Data = AddGeometries(path.Data, newGeometry1, scale1);

Geometry newGeometry2 = ...
double scale2 = ...
path.Data = CombineGeometries(path.Data, newGeometry2,
            GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, scale2);
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Appreciate your help. I'll try this. Even though ScaleTransform works, my application allows people to add more shapes and subtract or add again and the scaletransform throws everything out. Let me try your first one.

Comment: That produces the same result in that a path that is made up of rectangles and ellipses that have been "Excluded" only draws with one line. i'll add some images to show the difference.

Comment: Because you still have to have one polygon per path figure. You can't draw a set of unconnected figures with just one polygon. Please re-read the comments to my answer to your previous question.

Comment: And note that the ScaleTransform is applied to a *clone* of Path.Data, not the original geometry.

Comment: My application allows multiple people to draw on their own canvas at the same time via network. i need to take screen resolution into consideration when someone with 1920x1080 creates a combinedgeometry shape and it needs to re-create on remote pc's scaled to their resolution. the scaletransform works for the first reveal but resolution scales are out after that. ie: if some subtracts or adds another shape to the joint path.

Comment: The top image above is the received path object from a remote computer only using the original getflattenedpathgeometry(). It works with the excluded info but the wrong scale. here is where i need to apply a scale to each point and recreate from the same data. With the "M" "L" and such.

Comment: Looking at your images (and your code sample) I guess that you're perhaps simply ignoring each figure's `StartPoint`. Re-read my answer to your previous question. It adds the `StartPoint` before adding all the points from a figure's segments.

Comment: Thanks again Clemens for the edit. Each path that can get updated via the network can be a path made up of "Exclude" "Xor" or "Union" the best way i found was just to get the flattened geometry and scale that as it seemed to have everything that was needed to create the new path. I did try to find a way of seeing what method was used but the original geometry was just a path for Geometry1. No way of telling whether is was "Xor", "Exclude" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by perseverance.

The code to get each point of flattenedpathgeometry and add a scale to each point and recreate the same flattenedpathgeometry with the new points. hope it helps someone. And thanks Clemens. Appreciate your efforts.

```
path.Data = Geometry.Parse(CurrentObject.Geometry1);
PathGeometry g = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

PathGeometry g = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

foreach (var f in g.Figures)
{
Point pt1 = f.StartPoint;
pt1.X = pt1.X * ScaleX;
pt1.Y = pt1.Y * ScaleY;
strGeom += "M" + pt1.ToString();
    foreach (var s in f.Segments)
    if (s is PolyLineSegment)
    {
        count = 0;
        foreach (var pt in ((PolyLineSegment)s).Points)
    {
        int scount = ((PolyLineSegment)s).Points.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            Point pts = new Point(pt.X * ScaleX, pt.Y * ScaleY);
            strGeom += "L" + pts.ToString();
        }
        else if (count < scount)
        {
            Point pts = new Point(pt.X * ScaleX, pt.Y * ScaleY);
            strGeom += " " + pts.ToString();
        }
        else if (count == scount)
        {
            Point pts = new Point(pt.X * ScaleX, pt.Y * ScaleY);
            strGeom += " " + pts.ToString() + "Z";
        }
        count++;
    }
    }
}
path.Data = Geometry.Parse(strGeom);
```

Here's an image of the paths sent from a remote session: 1366x768 scales to 1920x1080

[image]

Comment: This is certainly the most complicated and inefficient way to combine geometries with different scaling factors. See the edit in my answer for how this could be done much more elegantly.

Comment: I added a comment to your original answer. The app uses "Xor", "Exclude" and "Union" and there's no way to find out what the original path is made up of when there are multiple modes. It seemed the best way to get the points and scale them was from the flattened geometry that worked but was a different size because of different screen resolutions. This is a very complicated app for collaboration so a few more lines added to the few hundred thousand seems ok. I have no doubt there's a better way but i haven't found it yet and this works. I've been working on it all day. cheers.